# Do stages in an application run parallel in spark?

Tags: apache-spark

I have a doubt that, how do stages execute in a spark application. Is there any consistency in execution of stages that can be defined by programmer or will it derived by spark engine?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Check the entities(stages, partitions) in this pic:**

[image]

[pic credits](http://alvincjin.blogspot.in/2014/12/stages-in-spark.html)

> Does stages in a job(spark application ?) run parallel in spark?

**Yes, they can be executed in parallel if there is no sequential dependency.**

Here Stage 1 and Stage 2 partitions can be executed in parallel but not Stage 0 partitions, because of dependency partitions in Stage 1 & 2 has to be processed.

> Is there any consistency in execution of stages that can be defined by
>   programmer or will it derived by spark engine?

Stage boundary is defined by when **data shuffling happens among partitions**. (check pink lines in pic)

Answer (score 4):

> How do stages execute in a Spark job

Stages of a job can run in parallel if there is no dependencies among them.

In Spark, stages are split by boundries. You have a shuffle stage, which is a boundary stage where transformations are split at, i.e. `reduceByKey`, and you have a result stage, which are stages that are bound to yield a result without causing a shuffle, i.e. a `map` operation:

[image: Spark stages]

[(Picture provided by Cloudera)](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2015/03/how-to-tune-your-apache-spark-jobs-part-1/)

Since `groupByKey` is a shuffle stage, you see the split in pink boxes which marks a boundary.

Internally,  a stage is further divided into tasks. e.g in the picture above, the first row which does `textFile -> map -> filter`, can be split into three tasks, one for each transformation.

When one transformations output is another transformations input, we need the serial execution. But, if stages are unrelated, i.e `hadoopFile -> groupByKey -> map`, they can run in parallel. Once they declare a dependency between them from that stage on they will continue execution serially.

Comment: Stages (i.e. their tasks) can run in parallel if there is no dependency between them and there is enough resources in a cluster to run the tasks.

Comment: @JacekLaskowski Thank you for the correction. I forgot about splitting a single transformation on a graph into multiple independent stages.