# Spark Shuffle partition - if I have shuffle partition less than number of cores what would happen?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am using databricks with Azure, so I don't have a way to provide the number of executors and memory per executors.

Let's consider I have the following configuration.

1. 10 Worker nodes, each with 4 cores and 10 GB of memory.
2. it's a standalone configuration
3. input read size is 100 GB

now if I set my shuffle partition to 10, (less than total cores, 40). What would happen?

will it create total of 10 executors, one per node, with each executor occupying all the cores and all the memory?

Comment: Wondering what the -1 was for, upvoted.

Comment: would someone please explain the reason for the downvote. it's not that I don't have the understanding of the topic, I wanted few more eyes to confirm things.

Comment: Agree, poorly... as I was llokig at the same thing yesterday as I am doing a DB Certification on MS AZURE...

Answer (score 1):

If you don't use `dynamic allocation`, you will end up leaving most cores unused during execution. Think about you have 40 "slots" for computation available, but only 10 tasks to process, so 30 "slots" will be empty (just idle).

I have to add that the above is a very simplified situation. In reality, you can have multiple stages running in parallel, so depending on your query, you will still have all 40 cores utilized (see e.g. [Does stages in an application run parallel in spark?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41340612/does-stages-in-an-application-run-parallel-in-spark))

Note also that `spark.sql.shuffle.partitions` is not the only parameter which determines the number of tasks/partitions. You can have different number of partitions for

- reading files
- if you modify your query using `repartition`, e.g. when using :

  ```
  df
   .repartition(100,$"key")
   .groupBy($"key").count
  ```

your value of `spark.sql.shuffle.partitions=10` will be overwritten by 100 in this exchange step

Comment: I logged in oddly enough to MS AZURE Databricks for a course for the 1st time yesterday.  Looking around the notebook and job story, I get the impression the settings as mentioned in the question cannot be maintained, but we need to rely on dynamic_allocation. Or have I missed something? Seems platforms do things simpler and thus more restrictive. Thanks in advance.

Comment: so will it be 10 executors or more than 10 executors and how many cors per executors ??

Answer (score 0):

What your discribing as an expectation is named dynamic allocation on Spark. You can provide min and max allocation and then depending on amount of partiton the framework will be scaled. https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#dynamic-allocation

But with only 10 partition on a 100 gb file you will have outOfMemoryErrors